# What is the difference between these two formulas of coefficient correlation?

Tags: correlation, regression-coefficients

In the book of "Practical Statistics for Data Scientists" it used the second formula(image down below) to calculate the coefficient correlation, while when I did some research in blogs and watched some YouTube tutorials most of them only use the pearson's formula .
So I'm asking is there any different between them , or any cases where we should use one better than the other
the Pearson's formula :
[image]

And the second one :
[image]

Comment: They are the same, assuming that the second uses $s_x^2=\frac1{n-1}\sum (x_i-\bar x)^2$ and similarly for  $s_y^2$

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70969, which gives 15 formulas or procedures to find $r.$  You are comparing the first two formulas (modulo the comment by @Henry).  The first formula is used only in textbooks because it is subject to (much) more floating point cancellation error than the second one.  The first one isn't terribly insightful, either: it's just a jumble of arithmetic.  The second begins to reveal some of the underlying *concepts* by exposing $r$ as a mean product of standardized residuals.

Comment: Thanks for the answers . I appreciate it .