Why is the correlation coefficient interpreted as the number of standard deviations in $y$ given one standard deviation of $x$ or viceversa?
I saw here in the answer to this question that the correlation coefficient between $X$ and $Y$ is interpreted as the number of standard deviations that $Y$ changes when $X$ changes in one standard deviation or viceversa. This comes from the formula:
$$\frac{cov(x, y)}{\sqrt{var(x)*var(y)}}$$
I get that this is suppossed to reflect an standarized measurement of the association between $x$ and $y$, but I don't know why. If ${\sqrt{var(x)*var(y)}}$ is supossed to be the standard deviation of $cov(x, y)$, I don't see how.

That square root is not the SD of the covariance.  It merely converts the units of measurement of $x$ and $y$ into standard units.

Perhaps a review of the characterizations of correlation coefficients at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70969 will answer your question outright or at least help you refine your question, whose nature is ambiguous: are you trying to ask about the SD of the covariance of two variables (and what would that mean?) or are you trying to elicit some kind of insight about this formula for correlation?
